# Advice on fundamental tutorial for server side rendering with React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, server-side-rendering

I've been reading everywhere for an up to date, detailed article/tutorial on how to implement server side rendering with React/Redux and React Router.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Ive literally found nothing, both react and redux's articles on this are just one pagers.

Thanks.

Comment: If server side rendering is really important for the project you are working on, you should definitely take a look at [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js)

Comment: @Coluccini Thanks for the advice. Isn't ssr important for every single page application, though?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you don't depend on organic traffic, your application is going to be use like a native app (something like twitter, spotify) or you know that your users don't have bad phones/connections, you can avoid having ssr.
I'm working in a really SEO dependent site and using next.js made our live so much easier.

Comment: Ssr isn't all about speed performance and SEO though. For example, my problem is not being able to refresh the page. Doing that will render "404 not found". That's in my opinion the biggest problem with one page applications.
Ive been looking in to next.js but since my website is ready to go, containing many lines of css, I'm not very excited about redoing all the styling (which next and all js code forces one to do).

Comment: The 404 issue is not related to ssr. It is related on how you configure your app and your server (if you have a router properly configured on your react app, you just have to configured your server to point any url to your app root and then the router will figure which component to show).
You can use your regular css files with next (I have a plain css file for all global styles and include it to the root html file in old way) or any other react app. At the end they all render html on the browser that can will be styled if there's a stylesheet included.

Comment: I'm using HostGator, with no server, node or anything running. Just the React build on the domains root directory. 

I wrap my root component in a "BrowserRouter", and then do "Redirects" and "Route"s in the App.js (the parent component). It's all working properly in localhost which, to my surprise,wasn't the case when the site went live. Do you know of any common mistakes as far as react routing or perhaps the problem is on hostgator directory?

Comment: If you load `/foo/bar` in the typical server it will look for the `bar` file inside de `foo` folder. But the react build creates a single `index.html` that load the js bundles and you need that the server load that file for any given url

Comment: Is there any common practice for doing that? The only thing hostgator seems to allow is just uploading my build through file manager, then it's their own 404 not found that shows up when refreshing. I dont know how to tell the server to always look for index.html, since that seem to be processed outside of my code. Any article you could point me to on this one?

Comment: Well, that depends on the type of server. It has nothing to do with react. I’ve never used hostgator, but if an Apache server you would usually use an .htaccess file for this. But no all server allow the use of htaccess files... maybe you should check the service called `now` from the same guys that made `next.js`. I think it will fit more for what you are trying to do